# How to programatically tell if a field is a taxonomy / managed metadata field?

Tags: 2010, list, managed-metadata, spfield

I am going after SPList.fields and getting the collection of fields...
I would like to eventually return only the fields that are managed meta data. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looping through the fields you will look for ones that are [TaxonomyFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.aspx)

```
if( fld is TaxonomyField ){
    //code here for metadata fields
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(field is TaxonomyField)
{
  Console.Writeline("Ok");
}
```